# Extract character string in middle of string with R

Tags: r, substring

I have character strings which look something like this:

`a <- c("miRNA__hsa-mir-521-3p.iso.t5:", "miRNA__hsa-mir-947b.ref.t5:")`

I want to extract the middle portion only eg. `hsa-mir-521-3p` and `hsa-mir-947b`

I have tried the following so far:

```r
a1 <- substr(a, 8,21) 
[1] "hsa-mir-521-3p" "hsa-mir-947b.r"
```

this obviously does not work because my desired substrings have varying lengths

```r
a2 <- sub('miRNA__', '', a)
[1] "hsa-mir-521-3p.iso.t5:" "hsa-mir-947b.ref.t5:"
```

this works to remove the upstream string (`“miRNA__”`), but I still need to remove the downstream string

Could someone please advise what else I could try or if there is a simpler way to achieve this? I am still learning how to code with R. Thank you very much!

Comment: In your second string example `hsa-mir-947-8p` the `8p` was not in the vector `a` (`hsa-mir-947b.ref.t5:`). May you correct this?

Comment: @iago you're absolutely right! thank you for pointing it out. i made a mistake here. it's supposed to be hsa-mir-947b. I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You haven't clearly defined the "middle portion" but based on the data shared we can extract everything between the last underscore (`"_"`) and a dot (`"."`).

```
sub('.*_(.*?)\\..*', '\\1', a)
#[1] "hsa-mir-521-3p" "hsa-mir-947b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex like below

```
> gsub(".*_|\\..*","",a)
[1] "hsa-mir-521-3p" "hsa-mir-947b"
```

which removes the left-most (`.*_`) and right-most (`\\..*`) parts, therefore keeping the middle part.

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(a, whitespace = '.*_|\\..*')
#[1] "hsa-mir-521-3p" "hsa-mir-947b"
```